# How to subset a string in R

Tags: r, string, substr

Dear all I have a vector of strings like:

```
LOCAT01PE
WECAT013EJD
AFECAT0155DR
```

I want to subset each value obtain only CAT and all the number after:

```
CAT01
CAT013
CAT0155
```

I have tried to use the command `substr` but it won't work since the quantity before the word CAT is not fixed and the numbers after CAT are not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `regexpr/regmatches` in `base R`.  It matches the word 'CAT' followed by `-` if there is any `?` and one or more digits (`\\d+`)

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("CAT-?\\d+", x))
#[1] "CAT01"    "CAT013"   "CAT0155"  "CAT-01"   "CAT-013"  "CAT-0155"
```

#### data

```
x <- c('LOCAT01PE', 'WECAT013EJD', 'AFECAT0155DR', 
    'LO-CAT-01PE', 'WE-CAT-013-EJD', 'AFE-CAT-0155-DR')
```

Comment: `x <- c('LO-CAT-01PE', 'WE-CAT-013-EJD', 'AFE-CAT-0155-DR')` How will the command change if I have "-" before and after CAT? thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 3):

In base R, we can use `sub` to extract "CAT" followed by numbers.

```
x <- c('LOCAT01PE', 'WECAT013EJD', 'AFECAT0155DR')
sub('..*(CAT\\d+).*', '\\1', x)
#[1] "CAT01"   "CAT013"  "CAT0155"
```

Or similar with `str_extract`

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "CAT\\d+")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `substr` with `regexpr` to identify relevant start/stop points in the string:

```
substr(vec,
       start = regexpr('CAT', vec),
       stop = regexpr('\\d[a-zA-Z]', vec)
       )
```

Output:

```
[1] "CAT01"   "CAT013"  "CAT0155"
```